# backbone fill collection after fetch() with POST verb

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

my rest api like this :

```
[POST]
http://172.22.5.250:3000/provinces/_search
```

that this api return a filtered data;

and I change fetch() method from GET to POST like this :

```
all(){
        let deferred=this.$q.defer();
        let provinces=new ProvinceRestCollection();
        provinces.fetch({
            method:"POST",
            url:"http://172.22.5.250:3000/provinces/_search",
            success: ()=> {
                deferred.resolve(provinces);
            },
            error: (err)=> {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

and use this service to controller like this :

```
let provinces = await this.prov.all();
        let combo=provinces.map(function (province) { return [province.id,province.title]});
        console.log(combo);
```

but fetch() method with POST verb not fill collection and my collection is empty

How fill collection after fetch() with POST verb ?

Answer (score 0):

`type:"POST"` instead of `method:"POST"`. Just tested and works fine.